# With Apollo React client, why you not always need a resolver to resolve @client GraphQL queries?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm learning how to use Apollo Client for React and how to manage local state using the cache.  From the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state), it's as simple as writing to the cache using `cache.writeData` and reading from it using a simple query.  Their example is

```
const GET_VISIBILITY_FILTER = gql`
  {
    visibilityFilter @client
  }
`;
```

I then wrap my JSX in a Query and can read the value fine (in my case `loggedIn`)

```
 return <Query query={GET_LOGGED_IN}>
      {({loading, error, data}) => {

        const {loggedIn} = data
```

I'm curious, though, why I don't need to write a resolver for this to work.  Is it because with scalar values if a value exists at the root of an object, that is, here at the top level of the cache, Apollo/GraphQL automatically just grabs that value and sends it to you without a resolver?

What are the limits of this, that is, could you grab arrays at the root level without writing a resolver?  Objects?  I'm assuming not, [as these don't seem to be scalars](https://medium.com/graphql-mastery/graphql-scalars-and-enums-part-1-built-in-scalars-overview-and-application-4a85f841698f).  But if the data is hard-coded, that is, doesn't require any DB lookup, the answer is still no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state):

> [The @client directive] tells Apollo Client to fetch the field data locally (either from the cache or using a local resolver), instead of sending it to our GraphQL server.

If the directive is present on a field, Apollo will attempt to resolve the field using the provided resolver, or fall back to fetching directly from the cache if one doesn't exist. You can initialize your cache with pretty much any sort of data at the root level (taking care to include `__typename` fields for objects) and you should be able to fetch it without having to also provide a `resolver` for it. On the other hand, providing a resolver can provide you with more granular control over what's actually fetched from the cache -- i.e. you could initialize the cache with an array of items, but use a resolver to provide a way to filter or sort them.

There's an import nuance here: Fetching without a resolver **only** works when there's data in the cache to fetch. That's why it's important to provide initial state for these fields when building your client. If you have a more deeply nested `@client` field (for example, maybe you're including additional information alongside data fetched from the server), you also technically don't have to write a resolver. But we typically do write them because there is no existing data in the cache for those nested fields.

Comment: Thanks. So the 'rules' for resolvers are slightly different than, say, on a Prisma GraphQL server, as we're dealing with the store?  I like the examples in the docs, but is there a more structured API description where I could better learn how exactly to use, for example,  `_typename`?  One thing that's been confusing me: I have found a lot of examples, tutorials and info that relate to `apollo-link-state` but as I understand it, that package has been merged into Apollo Client 2.5+.  But are the APIs exactly the same?  That is, the `apollo-link-state` example code works with Apollo Client 2.5?

Comment: Those are all excellent points, but unfortunately, no, at the moment that bit in the docs and [the official API reference](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client) are about it :(

Answer (score 1):

In addition to a great (as usual) answer from Daniel, I would like to add a few words.

You can use (read/write) objects to cache and manipulate its properties directly.

Using resolvers and mutations for local data can help with readability, data access/change unification, overal manageability or future changes (move feature/settings to server).

More practical/advanced example of local state managament you can find in [apollo-universal-starter-kit](https://github.com/sysgears/apollo-universal-starter-kit/blob/master/modules/user/client-react/resolvers/index.jsx) project.

Comment: How does one read directly from the cache?  That was the magic answer I was looking for but I couldn't find it -- I couldn't find `cache.readData` -- does it exist, or did I just miss it?